# How to install IBM mobile first platform studio 8.0 in eclipse Mars?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to IBM mobile first.I have installed eclipse Mars and also installed Mobile First platform 8.0 and Eclipse Hybrid Mobile (THyM) from Eclipse market place.Then installed node js.

Now I want to create a app and run in android device or emulator.But I am unable to do it.

Can anyone provide me the next steps I have to follow to work with IBM mobile first
?
System environment : Windows 7,Eclipse Mars, Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the final piece - the MobileFirst CLI. Install the CLI from command line: `npm install -g mfpdev-cli`.

The MobileFirst CLI is required for the MobileFirst Eclipse plug-in to function. The plug-in exposes CLI commands in the Eclipse UI.

You can then create applications and register them in the MobileFirst Server and other actions. Learn more in the following tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/using-mobilefirst-cli-in-eclipse/

Comment: Thanks Idan. Can u please clarify me the following questions...
How to add Adapters?
 whether I have to download Android Studio to develop android apps?  How to deploy the app in  IBM mobile first?
 What is the use of develop console? Is there any video which clearly explains about the installation and developing mobile app?

Comment: Did you at all take a look at the developer center tutorials? please do: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/. 1) you create adapters using the CLI. See the adapters tutorials. 2) you do not deploy apps, you only need to register them. See the tutorials.

Comment: how to run MobileFirst Server to run locally?

Comment: Why do you not read? Download the developer kit. See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add platforms ? (Whenever I register the app it says No platform were detected)

Comment: You can add a platform either via command line using the Cordova CLI, or using the THyM plugin as instructed in the tutorial. See the video at this timestamp: https://youtu.be/yRe2AprnUeg?t=80 - and the tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/using-mobilefirst-cli-in-eclipse/#creating-a-cordova-project

Comment: I created the app using eclipse through the steps given in the document,I didn't find any files in platforms and for adding server in eclipse I didn't have the servers view.So I zipped my project ,imported it in console and I got an error "FWLSE3051E: Invalid payload. See additional messages for details. FWLSE2302E: Can't read the content: failed to extract data from the zip format. Malformed ziped content." Likewise when I used CLI I add my server and when tried to register my app mfpdev app register, I receive an error message as No platforms were detected ...Where did I go wrong ???